# Mongo - Open Food Facts dataset - How to find all products that contains a certain substring in a string

Tags: string, mongodb, search, mongodb-query, substring

I'm working with the Open Food Facts dataset (`wget https://static.openfoodfacts.org/data/openfoodfacts-mongodbdump.tar.gz`) on Mongo DB.

I'm trying to get all the products from the table `db.products` for which the string `ingredients_text` contains a certain text (water,garlic,...) and don't have any `category`.

I've searched thoroughly on other topics and threads, and I came to this query:

`db.products.find({categories:{$in:[null,""]},ingredients_text:{$in:[/water/,/garlic/i]}}).count()`

Can we agree this gives me all products with no `category`, and for which the `ingredients_text` string contains either water (not case sensitive) or garlic (not case sensitive)?

Many thanks!

Arnaud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query. I hope so it will work, as you are passing regular expression in **"in"** operator it will not work. you have to use **$regex** for it

```
db.products.find({categories:{$in:[null,""]},ingredients_text:{$regex:"(water|garlic)",$options:"$i" }}).count();
```

()